# NSButton Rounded Corners without Subclassing

Tags: ios, cocoa

Is there anyway to create a NSButton with rounded corners and background color without subclassing it. I have this code and it does not do anything.

```
 let directionsButton = NSButton(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 60))
        directionsButton.title = "Click Me!"
        directionsButton.layer?.cornerRadius = 10
        directionsButton.layer?.masksToBounds = true
        directionsButton.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable the CoreAnimation layer you have to insert this line before using it

```
directionsButton.wantsLayer = true
```

**Edit:** To be able to change the color you have to draw a borderless button. Add

```
directionsButton.isBordered = false
```

Comment: Thanks! I added wantsLayer but the button still shows text. I can see background in the back but not filled correctly. See the image in original question.

Comment: Please see the edit.